# How to to get difference of values with Latest Date in table and previous date values in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get the difference (using Oracle SQL )of sizes between the max date record and previous day and also max date record and 7 day before date.

```
Date          Size
-----        ------
26-Aug-19     20
25-Aug-19     10
24-Aug-19     30
23-Aug-19     40
22-Aug-19     14
21-Aug-19     16
20-Aug-19     19
19-Aug-19     21
```

I am able to do using SYSDATE in decode. But Cannot solve using GREATEST(Date) in decode statements.Have to get the Latest date and then do a Latestdate-1 and LatestDate-7 and then find the difference.

Desired Result:

```
Date          Diff Size 1d    Diff Size 1w
-----        -------------    ------------
26-Aug-19     10               -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this assuming that there is single row for each day

```
SELECT DATE, DIFF_SIZE_ID, DIFF_SIZE_1W FROM
(SELECT DATE,
SIZE - LAG(SIZE,1) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS DIFF_SIZE_ID,
SIZE - LAG(SIZE,7) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS DIFF_SIZE_1W,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE DESC NULLS LAST) AS RN
FROM TABLE)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: @soumitra chatterjee this gives results for the records for 1 or 7 prior `rank` for max(date) but not the results for 1 or 7 `days` before. Consider the data set here : [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e99bd0364a54e7d3dbee9ca7fe88bccc)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `max("Date") over (order by "Date" desc)` to detect the greatest date and non-null values of `first_value("Size") over ( order by "Date" desc ) - "Size"` by  comparison with `"Date"` column :

```
select max(max_date) as "Date", 
       max(day_before) as "Diff Size 1d", 
       max(week_before) as "Diff Size 1w"
  from
  (
   select max("Date") over (order by "Date" desc) max_date,
          case when max("Date") over (order by "Date" desc) - 1 = "Date" then
               first_value("Size") over ( order by "Date" desc ) - "Size"
          end day_before,  
          case when max("Date") over (order by "Date" desc) - 7 = "Date" then
               first_value("Size") over ( order by "Date" desc ) - "Size"
          end week_before
     from tab);

Date        Diff Size 1d    Diff Size 1w
---------   ------------    ------------
26-AUG-19   10              -1
```

P.S. this works provided you have records with date `max("Date") - 1` or `max("Date") - 7`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=625585ae6ef2981deb3d103c705a4290)</kbd>